# Not getting success in calling asp.net web service from sencha touch

Tags: android, web-services, sencha-touch

Here's my code which i am using to get data from web service:-

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 
      var url = "http://192.168.1.15/JSONDemo/Service1.asmx/getString";
     Ext.Ajax.request({

        method: 'get',
        url: url,
    //  params: {'name':'himanshu'},
        jsonData: { 'name': 'Himanshu'},
    //   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' },
        success: function (response, request) { 
        alert('Working!') 
        alert(response.responseText)
        console.log('Response:-'+response.responseText)
        },
        failure: function (response, request) {
        alert('Not working!')
        console.log('Response Status:-'+response.status)
        }
        });
});
```

my .net web service code is here:-

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string getString(string name)
        {
            return "Hello "+name;
        }
```

I am getting no response with this code with '0' response status.Please help me get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get data from your service using a web browser?
When using http get you should pass the parameters to the method in query string. Is sencha passing the parameters in query string?
Best regards